# MYSQL UDF sockets

Tags: mysql, c, performance, sockets

I've created a MySQL User defined function to open a unix domain type socket.

My problem is that if I call my function directly like so:

```
SELECT socketOpen("/path/to/file", "message");
```

It always executes in <10ms. So that is nice. But since I don't want to manually call this function everytime, I've created a stored procedure which does an insert into database and then calls this function.

The problem I'm facing is that the stored procedure **usually** takes <10ms, but somestimes takes over 1s. Even 5s. I don't understand how this happens. Is there a caching problem or something ?

Below is the code is use, stripped of error checking for clarity:

```
char *socketOpen(UDF_INIT *initid __attribute__((unused)),
               UDF_ARGS *args, char *result, unsigned long *length,
               char *is_null, char *error __attribute__((unused)))
{
    int sockfd, portno, n, servlen;
    struct sockaddr_un serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    char socket_path[100];
    char message[100];

    memcpy(socket_path,args->args[0],args->lengths[0]);
    socket_path[args->lengths[0]] = 0;
    memcpy(message,args->args[1],args->lengths[1]);
    message[args->lengths[1]] = 0;

    sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(serv_addr.sun_path, args->args[0]);

    servlen=strlen(serv_addr.sun_path) + sizeof(serv_addr.sun_family);
    connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, servlen);

    n = write(sockfd, message, strlen(message));

    bzero(message,100);

    n = read(sockfd, message, 100);

    close(sockfd);
    strcpy(result, message);
    *length = strlen(message);
    return result;
}
```

I would appreciate your insight into this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I've got no replies and I've fixed the problem I would like to share my solution to the problem.

The cause of the problem was quite different than I ancipated.

The machine of running the above code was Raspberry pi, which slowness I did not take into account. As it turns out most of the delay was caused by the UPDATE statement in the procedure. As soon as I changed the table ENGINE to `MyISAM` everything went smooth from then on.

Altough while testing the code there was sometimes still a slight delay. I've fixed that with making the socket non-blocking. That means that if something will go wrong the socket will never be opened, but I figure that is better than blocking indefinetely.